# Как константой $_GET передать нужное значение?

Tags: php, get

Всем привет!)  Задача следующая -> Есть база данных, в которую с помощью формы мы добавляем записи, выводим их и так же нажимая на ссылку удалить, удаляем их. Вот именно с удалением возникли проблемы. Не могу понять Как мне в `$_GET['id']` с помощью ссылки передать id, у меня там постоянно название файла. Ссылка для удаления находиться в блоке  `/* Вывод записей из БД */`, а удаляю с помощью блока `/* Удаление записи из БД *`/.

```
 <?php
/* Основные настройки */

define(DB_HOST, 'localhost');
define(DB_LOGIN, 'root');
define(DB_PASSWORD, "");
define(DB_NAME, 'sbook');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

/* Основные настройки */

/* Сохранение записи в БД */

if(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST'){
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
    $msg = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'msg');
}

     if (!$name) {
    $errors[] = 'Name can not to be empty';
    }

    if (!$email) {
    $errors[] = 'Email empty or invalid';
    } else {
    $select = "SELECT email FROM msgs WHERE email='{$email}';";

    $email_exists = mysqli_query($link, $select);
    $email_exists = mysqli_fetch_all($email_exists);

    if (!empty($email_exists)) {
        $errors[] = 'This email is exists';
    }
    }
if (!$errors) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO msgs (name, email, msg) VALUES ('$name',
'$email', '$msg');";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
/* Сохранение записи в БД */

/* Удаление записи из БД */

if (isset($_GET['id'])){

    $id = ($_GET['id']);
    echo "$id";

    $query ="DELETE FROM msgs WHERE id = '$id'";

    mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
}

/* Удаление записи из БД */
?>
<h3>Оставьте запись в нашей Гостевой книге</h3>

<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>">
Имя: <br /><input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Email: <br /><input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Сообщение: <br /><textarea name="msg"></textarea><br />

<br />

<input type="submit" value="Добавить" />

</form>

<?php
/* Вывод записей из БД */

    $count = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM msgs LIMIT 300;");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($count);

    if ($count)
        $count = mysqli_fetch_all($count, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    else 
        false;

    if(is_array($count) && !empty($count)) {
        foreach ($count as $key) {
            ?>
            <p>
                <?= $key['id']; ?>
                <?= $key['name']; ?>
                <?= $key['email']; ?>
                <?= $key['msg']; ?>
                <?= $key['datetime'];?>
            </p>
            <p align="right"><a href="http://mysite.ru/index.php?id=gbook&id=<?=$id?>"> // КАК ЗДЕСЬ ПРАВИЛЬНО НАПИСАТЬ ЗАПРОС????
Удалить</a></p>

            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <p>No items</p>
        <?php 
    }


    mysqli_close($link);
?>
<p>Всего записей в гостевой книге: <?= $num_rows;?></p>
```

Comment: начните с того, чтобы удаление сделать через post-запрос.

Comment: @teran По условию, этот запрос должен быть GET

Comment: GET-запросы по идеологии своей не предназначены для внесения измнений в БД, только получение сведений. Для остального есть post, put, delete

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в том, что  вы передаете в `index.php?id=` (Это и соответствует  $_GET['id']) одно значение, а потом снова передаете туда же и значения перезаписываются. Тоже самое, если вы в 1 переменную передадите 2 значения, естественно отобразиться останется только то, что было записано последним.

Сделайте запрос таким `index.php?act=gbook&id=ТУТ ID`

Ну и принимать их соответственно через. `$_GET['act']` `$_GET['id']` Можете конечно просто разбирать потом `$_GET` данные там будут в виде массива.